# Algorithm intuition: transform but with possibly more output items than input items?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to escape a string. That is, I want to copy characters, but where the input has `"` or `\`, I want to prepend `\` on the output. I can write that easily enough, even very generically:

```
//! Given a range of code units (e.g., bytes in utf-8), transform them to an output range.
//! If a code unit needs escaping (per the given predicate), insert esc before that code unit in the output.
template <typename InRange, typename OutIter, typename NeedsEscapingPred, typename EscCodeUnit>
OutIter transformEscapeCodeUnits(const InRange& in, OutIter out,
     NeedsEscapingPred needsEscaping,
     EscChar esc) {
     for (const auto& codeUnit : in) {
         if (needsEscaping(codeUnit)) {
             *out++ = esc;
         }
         *out++ = codeUnit;
     }
     return out;
}

//! Convenience overload for common case:
template <typename InRange, typename OutIter>
OutIter transformEscapeCodeUnits(const InRange& in, OutIter out, char esc = '\') {
    return transformEscapeCodeUnits(in, out, [](auto c) { return c == '\' || c == '"'; }, esc);
}
```

However, in the spirit of "no raw loops", I looked at the algorithm and numeric header in search of a generic algorithm to do this. There's `replace_if` and `replace_copy_if` and `remove_if`, but I'm not seeing any std algorithms that take a sequence and output a potentially-longer sequence. This would be basically `insert_copy_if`, or even more generically, something like `transform_items`:

```
//! Like transform, but TransformItem takes an element and an iterator and writes zero or more output elements:
template <typename InRange, typename OutIter, typename TransformItem>
OutIter transform_items(InRange&& inRange, OutIter out, TxFn transformItem) {
    for (auto&& x : std::forward<InRange>(inRange)) {
        out = transformItem(std::forwrad<decltype(x)>(x), out);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then the escaping case would call `transform_items(in, out, [shouldEsc, esc](auto c, auto out) { if (shouldEsc(c)) { *out++ = esc; } *out++ = c; })`.

Am I missing something, or is there nothing quite like that in the standard library?

Comment: What's getting missed here is the fact that, in a practical world, Buzzword Bingo has no value, and nobody is going to be awarded a shiny medal, of some sort, for managing to avoid an explicit loop (and instead having the compiler generate the exact same loop, implicitly) when implementing some particular algorithm.

Comment: To be clear, in production code, I can write the raw loop, but I see a lot of value in finding the patterns in code and better understanding what the standard library provides, and what it's missing. I find this particularly true in parallel programming when a loop may be hard to parallelize but a call to an algorithm may be easy to parallelize. For example, `std::inclusive_scan` can compute the partial sum of integers in parallel, when it's not obvious that that would even be possible.

Comment: you could write an iterator to iterate "tokens" rather than single characters. `"` in the input would be a single token and `\"` in the output can be a single token. The out put iterator can be a foward iterator that when assigned to appends to the actual string. Didn't think it trough completely, but anyhow this would defeat your motivation of being able to easily parallelize it

Comment: could `transform` (creating strings, not char) and then `accumulate` to flatten and join the strings work ?

Comment: @AloisChristen definitely. But then you have an alloc per char (OK, small-string optimization, but still a lot of overhead). I feel like this `transform_items` algorithm is pretty good. It also could be parallelized by having threads build separate `std::vector`s then blit them all into the output. (And if the output iterator is random-access, the parallel version could parallel partial-sum the results to find the offsets into the result, and parallel `std::copy` into the result.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the general question, but `std::quoted` does your explicit example. Perhaps the implementation of it could guide your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking on Twitter, I got some very satisfying answers, although it involves the M-word (monad).

First, @atorstling
suggests that this is `flatMap` in JavaScript: https://twitter.com/atorstling/status/1574097704098988033?s=20&t=jzS503R6fMOqCajReygzJg https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-array-flatmap/

So translating to C++, I think the answer to my question is that this should be called `flat_transform`. With pedantic use of forwarding, that's:

```
//! Like transform, but TransformItem takes an element and an iterator and writes zero or more output elements:
template <typename InRange, typename OutIter, typename TransformOne>
OutIter flat_transform(InRange&& inRange, 
                       OutIter out,
                       TransformOne transform_one) {
    for (auto&& x : std::forward<InRange>(inRange)) {
        out = transform_one(std::forwrad<decltype(x)>(x), std::move(out));
    }
    return out;
}
```

and yes, this appears to be a "missing algorithm" from the STL.

But additionally, @salociN001 pointed out that "It's basically the monadic bind operation: Transforming a Container of A with a function taking A and returning a container of A into a flat container of A." https://twitter.com/salociN001/status/1573918982557548545?s=20&t=jzS503R6fMOqCajReygzJg

So there we have it:

- It's monadic bind.
- A reasonable C++ name is `flat_transform`.
- It is, in fact, a missing algorithm.